# VBA- variable in a range, inside a formula

Tags: vba, variables

I have the following code, to calculate the max in a range of cells:

```
 Range("E3").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-3]:R[50]C[-3])"
```

How can I replace 50 with a variable in my code?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
Dim sVal as String
sVal = "50"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-3]:R[" & sVal & " ]C[-3])"
```

Comment: Great I had forgotten the &&. Thanks a lot for your quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Dim somevar as Integer
somevar = 50
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-3]:R[" + somevar + "]C[-3])"
```

Comment: Although this would work, using '+' to concatenation strings is not recommended.
The & operator is recommended for string concatenation because it is defined exclusively for strings and reduces your chances of generating an unintended conversion.

Comment: Agreed.  I use both, but I am also mindful of when those unintended conversions could cause issue.