# VBA: DateDiff not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file that automatically timestamps entries as they are added. I want a script that finds the time difference in minutes between the first and last entry. This is what I've come up with so far.

```
Sub Duration()

Dim lRow As Long Dim lValue Dim fValue Dim Duration As Long, n As Integer

'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lValue = Cells(lRow, 5).Value
MsgBox (lValue)
fValue = Cells(5, 5).Value
MsgBox (fValue)
Duration = DateDiff("n", "fValue", "lValue")
MsgBox (Duration)

Cells(3, 5) = Duration 

End Sub
```

Comment: Try like this:     `Duration = DateDiff("n", fValue, lValue)`

Comment: @Vityata is correct, you're using string literals where it should be the the variable names.  It's trying to find a difference of dates from 2 nonconforming strings of characters.  Assuming the cells have dates, this should work after that.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it! I know it's an amateur mistake, still new to programming. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Related (not quite dupe): http://stackoverflow.com/q/10098802/1188513

Comment: In the future, try compiling and running your code before you ask a question about it. In this case, it's fairly obvious what the problem is when you get the "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" that highlights the line with your syntax error\typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateDiff` takes 3 arguments:

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

All the arguments can be given as variables as well. In your case, try with:

```
Duration = DateDiff("n", fValue, lValue)
```

If you like to make it with less lines, you may even go for:

```
Duration = DateDiff("n", Cells(5, 5).Value, Cells(lRow, 5).Value)
```

For details, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx.

Comment: Welcome, @LeeSin - its not an amature mistake, there is a set of mistakes that everyone should make at least once to become better :)

Comment: I try to subscribe to what Groucho said: “Learn from the mistakes of others. You can never live long enough to make them all yourself.”

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn - it really depends on the sector you are working at. Fortunately we are not jet pilots. :)