# 1004 error for range argument

Tags: vba, excel

I have another simple syntax question that I can't quite figure out. I want to change all the cells in a column so they have a **bottom border** and have a variable to figure out the last night with data on it.

My code is below and I believe the **error** is how I am trying to define the last cell.

```
wsSheet.Range("F11:wsSheet.Cells(LastRowForSig, 6)").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

Comment: How did you declare `wsSheet`?

Comment: As a worksheet: Dim wsSheet As Worksheet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10098802/1188513 - you have code that's meant to be executable, enclosed in double quotes; VBA only sees a string literal then.

Comment: Based on that comment, I changed the above code to      `wsSheet.Range("F11", wsSheet.Cells(LastRowForSig, 6)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous` but it just gives me the border on the last row rather than all of the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
With wsSheet.Range("F11", wsSheet.Cells(LastRowForSig, 6)).Borders
    .value = 1
    .item(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    .item(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    .item(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You should accept E. Trauger's answer, but here is a slight variation

```
With wsSheet
    .Range("F11", .Cells(LastRowForSig, 6)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With
```

Comment: Do I need to change something to get the border to show on all the cells in the column because right now it is just showing up on the very bottom cell of the column.

Comment: That's because you've only specified the bottom border. Replace `Borders(xlEdgeBottom)` with `Borders`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below

```
Dim r1 as Range, r2 as Range
Set r1 = wsSheet.Range("F11")
Set r2 = wsSheet.Cells(LastRowForSig, 6)

wsSheet.Range(r1 & ":" & r2).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

Edited after request.

Comment: I tried it and am still getting the 1004 method range of object worksheet failed error.

Comment: to be a little nitpicky, make sure you have a space between the `&` and any arguments. Sometimes VBA doesn't add it automatically and I've gotten errors before.

Comment: Try with the new edits.  I am not sure why the previous version did not work.

Comment: I see where my error is now. r2 or whatever the cell value is being returned rather than the cell address. So right now my r2 is Qty. Loaded (a string rather than say F14.

Comment: @vba_n00b Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank you for all of the help. I ended up using the following: `With wsSheet.Range("F11", wsSheet.Cells(LastRowForSig, 6)).Borders
            .Value = 1
            .Item(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Item(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Item(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
        End With`