# how to set a range by the column header

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a VBA code to compare by using v-lookup. In that I am declaring ranges by A2/B2 or some thing like that
I want to declare the range by Column headers as these headers are static but for every sheet those columns will be re arranged

```
Dim PLACE_OF_SERVICE As String
Dim SERVICE_CODE As String
Dim DIAGNOSIS_CODE As String
Dim REVENUE_CODE As String
Dim NDC_CODE As String
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("O1") = "Observation"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("O2").Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Range(SERVICE_CODE)),Valuesets!$A$2:$A$5,1,FALSE))=FALSE),""Yes"",""No"")"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("O2").AutoFill Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("O2:O" & last)
```

The actual formula is 
IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(F2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,1,FALSE))=FALSE),"Yes","No")
But I want to write it with column header by replacing F2

Comment: You can get the range the header is in with a `Find` or `Application.Match`.

Comment: I am new to coding and I just gave a try....
Can you please help me

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098802/vba-variable-in-a-range-inside-a-formula

Comment: If you format your data as a table (Ctrl+T), then you can use the header in your formula, another option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: (You will need to custom it, because the only thing we can deduce from your code is that F2 is "SERVICE_CODE")

```
Dim PLACE_OF_SERVICE As String
Dim SERVICE_CODE As String
Dim DIAGNOSIS_CODE As String
Dim REVENUE_CODE As String
Dim NDC_CODE As String

Range ("??").Name = "PLACE_OF_SERVICE" 'Replace ?? by PLACE_OF_SERVICE Range
Range ("F2").Name = "SERVICE_CODE"
Range ("??").Name = "DIAGNOSIS_CODE" 'Replace ?? by DIAGNOSIS_CODE Range
Range ("??").Name = "REVENUE_CODE" 'Replace ?? by REVENUE_CODE Range
Range ("??").Name = "NDC_CODE" 'Replace ?? by NDC_CODE Range

With Application.Worksheets("Data")
    .Range("O1") = "Observation"
    .Range("O2").Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(SERVICE_CODE, _
                    Valuesets!$A$2:$A$5,1,FALSE))=FALSE),""Yes"",""No"")"
    .Range("O2").AutoFill Destination:= .Range("O2:O" & last)
End With
```

Anyhow, this code will lookup by the value that you have on F2 cell, f.e., another subject is if you are trying to look for the items on one column, not one cell.